# Insert data in AWS Redshift via AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to do the following:

When I upload a csv file in AWS S3, AWS Lambda need to detect it and create a table in AWS Redshift and store the data in it. This procedure works without lambda. But I want to automate it.

So, I made a lambda function to detect the upload op a csv file and so on..

Now after some error solving I get an error that says nothing to me..

```
Loading function
START RequestId: e8baee71-c36b-11e5-b1cb-87083ac95a25 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: e8baee71-c36b-11e5-b1cb-87083ac95a25
REPORT RequestId: e8baee71-c36b-11e5-b1cb-87083ac95a25  Duration: 67.04 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB
```

This is my lambda python file. It is in the root of my zip file. In the zip file their is one other map 'psycopg2'

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import boto3
import psycopg2
import linecache

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

        #SEND MAIL WHEN CREATED

        #from = "email@gmail.com"
        #password = "password.email"
        #mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        #mail.ehlo()
        #mail.starttls()
        #mail.login(from,password)

        #recipient = "recipient.email"
        #mail.sendmail(from,recipient,key)


        #CREATE REDSHIFT TABLE WHEN CSV FILE UPLOADED
        if(key == "*.csv"):
            conn_string = "dbname=" + "xxxx" + " port=" + "5439" + " user=" + "yyyyy" + " password=" + "xxxxx*" + " host=" + "xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com";
            connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
            cursor = connection.cursor();

            cursor.execute("select exists(select * from information_schema.tables where table_name=%s)", (key,))
            if(cursor.fetchone()[0]):
                return
            else:
                sqlcommand = 'create table ' + key + '('

                line = linecache.getline(key,1)
                line = line.replace(' ', '')
                line = line.replace('/', '')
                line = line.replace(':', '')
                line2 = linecache.getline(key,2)
                df1 = line
                df2 = line2
                output = ''
                output2 = ''
                for row1 in df1:
                    output = output + row1

                for row2 in df2:
                    output2 = output2 + row2

                new = output.split(',')
                new2 = output2.split(',')
                i = 0;
                for var in new:
                    new2[i] = new2[i].replace(' ', '')
                    sqlcommand = sqlcommand + var + ' ' + self._strType(new2[i])
                    i = i + 1;
                sqlcommand = sqlcommand[:-1]
                sqlcommand = sqlcommand + ');'

                cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
                connection.commit();

                print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
                return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Comment: You could try and use some print statements in your lambda handler ourtside of the IF statement to see if it actually enters that code block..

Comment: I'd suggest adding in some [logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html) so that you can see more clearly what is going on during the lifetime of your Lambda function execution. All that output block above shows is the timing and billing metrics of how long your function took to run.

Comment: @birryree : if i place "logger.info("text")" in my code. I can't check that in the logs file in amazon? Where can I check them?

Comment: @user5488652 The Amazon Cloudwatch logs for your lambda function will have the log output from your function.

Comment: @birryree : the logger.info("text") is not showing there.. I only see the error shown in the question..

Comment: @user5488652 You also have to explicitly grant permission to your Lambda function to be able to write logs to Cloudwatch, see the [documentation for help](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#lambda-intro-execution-role).

Comment: @birryree: thx for helping. Did that, but no result yet

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am also have a hellish time with Lambda + Redshift + Python

Comment: @PhilMcParlane Is your issue concerning the logs (like it has been discussed above) or the actual lambda+redshift+python? I have something working on my side. Did you make sure to compile psycopg2 on an AMI and deliver its native dependencies as part of the package to upload to Lambda?

Comment: @Ptah thanks for replying but I eventually resolved my problem by switching from the 'dependent' psycopg2 PG driver to the pure python pg8000 driver

Comment: @user5488652 I am getting the following error --- 


"Unable to import module 'copy': /var/task/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: ELF file's phentsize not the expected size"

Answer (score 7):

That's not an error.  That's what success looks like.